# fluentvalidation in BLL & DAL- circular reference

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, fluentvalidation

I am working on a multilayered project.

My BLL project contains all my models with its associated validation rules.
My DAL project makes the connection to the DB, defines my project context and has a reference to BLL models to define the mapping.

Eveything worked fine until I needed to add a new rule to verify the uniqueness of staff name using FluentValidation.

**Example of my Staff model and my Staff validation rules in my BLL:**

```
[Validator(typeof(StaffValidator))]
public class STAFF
{
    public string FullName { get; set; }
}

public class StaffValidator : AbstractValidator<STAFF>
    {    
    public StaffValidator()
        {
                RuleFor(cmd => cmd.FullName ).Must(BeUniqueName)
                    .WithMessage("This staff already exists");
        }

        private bool BeUniqueName(STAFF Thestaff, string fullName)
            {
                MyContext _context = new MyContext ();
                var dbStaff = _context.STAFF
                                    .Where(x => x.fullName.ToLower() == fullName.ToLower())
                                    .SingleOrDefault();

                if (dbStaff == null)
                    return true;

                return dbStaff.ID == Thestaff.ID;
            }
    }
```

In order to do that in my validation class in BLL, I need to use my context from my DAL which is impossible as my DAL is already referencing my BLL and I can't do the other way round because of circular references.

I have then tried to put all my validation logic in a separate layer ("validation") which calls both BLL for the models and DAL for the context.

However, I doesn't work either as I can not decorate my model in the BLL with the Validator attribute (circular reference issue again) referencing the AbstractValidator from my Validation layer.

```
[Validator(typeof(StaffValidator))]
```

So, is there a way of doing what I want to do? Can I define the Validator attribute elsewhere?

I realize that the way how I have layered my whole project cause a difficulty in that case but I can't change it now. So any advices on how to implement this unique rule in fluentvalidation would be very welcome.

Thank you for your help.

Sylvain

Comment: The uniqueness of an entity is not a concern of that object itself but of its collection. That's what you're running into, Domain validation should be autonomous. This particular validation should be part of a BRL (not BLL/Domain) layer. So the solution depends on the rest of your architecture.

Comment: Thanks @HenkHolterman. This is what I tried to do by adding this Validation layer in order to take care of the bussiness rules. However, since the model in my DAL has to be decorated by the Validator attribute in order to make it work. Ho can I do that? Can I have a deriving model in my BRL on which I will puty my Validator attribute in order to make the separation or concerns? Any advices and examples would be welcome